# C++ overloaded operator to return the derived class object not the base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, operator-overloading, derived-class

Say I have a template class in which I overload one of the operators, lets say a multiplication operator:

```
template <typename T1>
class base_matrix{

  public:
  T1* M; 
  ....

  base_matrix<T1>& operator*=(const complex<double>& f){  
    for(int i=0;i<n_elts;i++) { M[i] *= (T1)f; }
    return *this;
  }

  friend base_matrix<T1> operator*(const int& f, const base_matrix<T1>& ob){
    base_matrix<T1> res(ob);  res *= f; return res;
  }
}
```

Then I define a derived class with a specialized template parameter:

```
class CMATRIX : public base_matrix< complex<double> >{

public:


}
```

In my understanding, since the operators are inherited in the derived class, one can create an object of type CMATRIX and multiply it by a complex number. What I expect to get is another object of the type CMATRIX. What I actually get is the object of the base class type (with the substituted template argument) 
`base_matrix< complex<double> >`. This is kinda clear - the derived object calls the base class method, which returns the base class object.

Sure, I could do an explicit conversion in the derived class:

```
friend CMATRIX operator*(const CMATRIX& ob, const complex<double>& f){     
  return CMATRIX(ob * f);
}
```

but it seems like an unnecessary redefinition of the operator overload. That is - if I need to explicitly redefine all the operator overloads in the derived class - what is the point of defining them in the base class?

So, this is one of my questions. Another, more technical - how do I actually make the derived class operator return the right (derived) class without explicit conversion?

Comment: Why is `CMATRIX` a derived class, and not simply a typedef for `base_matrix< complex<double> >` ?

Comment: it contains additional methods, not applicably to a generic matrix..

Comment: Make it a template specialization then.

Comment: Thanks, @IgorTandetnik, for the hint! While I'm learning this new topic, could you perhaps show an example of how you would modify this code?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I have played with the template specialization. Overall, it could be a good design strategy, but the problem with it is that I'd need to re-implement same operators and functions for each specific type T1. Using  inheritance seems to be more logical, but then I hit the above mentioned problem...

Answer (score 3):

Not a great solution but...

You can insert the `friend` operator in a template base class that whose template argument is the derived class (CRTP style).

An example

```
#include <complex>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct multM
 {
  friend T operator* (int const f, T const & ob)
   { T res(ob); res *= f; return res; }
 };

template <typename T1>
class base_matrix : public multM<base_matrix<T1>>
 {
   public:
      T1 *        M; 
      std::size_t n_elts;

      base_matrix<T1>& operator*=(const std::complex<double>& f){  
         for(int i=0;i<n_elts;i++) { M[i] *= (T1)f; }
         return *this;
      }
 };

class CMATRIX : public base_matrix<std::complex<double>>,
                public multM<CMATRIX>
 { };

int main()
 {
   static_assert(std::is_same<base_matrix<float>,
                    decltype(int{}*base_matrix<float>{})>::value, "!");
   static_assert(std::is_same<CMATRIX,
                    decltype(int{}*CMATRIX{})>::value, "!!");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, @max66, I'll keep this in mind, but you are right - seems a bit too complicated, especially considering there are more than just one operator that needs to be overloaded.

Comment: @not a great solution but... you can put all overloaded operators in the same base class... I suppose